# Adding comment (e.g. description) to views, tables, etc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to add a short description to views, tables, etc. in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use [extended properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243(SQL.90).aspx).

(It can also be done via SSMS I think)